# What is maximum number of parameter sets that can added to a PreparedStatement Batch Update?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I need to execute over 100000 insert statements, like the following via jdbc:

```
Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
String sql = "Insert Into Table (ColA, ColB) Values(?, ?)";  
String[][] params = /*some array*/

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);  
for(String[] var : params)  
{  
    statement.setString(1, var[0]);  
    statement.setString(2, var[1]);  
    statement.addBatch();  
}    

statement.executeBatch();
```

I thought this would be a common question but I can't seem to find any definite answer to this question. Its a cross database project.

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on your MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET setting in MySQL (if that's what you're using).

The default max packet size for MySQL is 16 MB on the client.

You can update the value by either:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=64M
```

or

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=64M
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Of course this is assuming you're using MySQL. Other databases may have different settings.

Comment: I am not allowed to modofy any database settings. Also it is a cross database project - mainly dealing with db2, oracle and SQL Server. 
But thanks for pointing me to the MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET variable, there must be similar variables for the other dbs,

Comment: Man that's tough that you have no control over the DB. Best thing I could tell you is to break up your 100K statements into batches of 500 or something. Of Course, I'd unit test it first using different JDBC drivers to make sure it works for all your databases that you're using. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

i think the only limitation would be disk working space and memory.  see this discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/d16af627-d374-4ac2-ba6d-017729fe3206

You should be able to simulate this with a unit test (JUnit).  Managing this through a transaction would also save you a big headache if it dies halfway through.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a common question because there are other ways to do this. My personal suggestion would be to create a stored procedure that takes in prepared data (like an XML document) and does it in a true batch format.

Comment: Stored procs would've been my pref too, but we have no database priveleges, not allowed to change it in any way.

Comment: :( Sorry to hear that. Usually, privileges on a db are locked down to stored procedures as straight TSQL is more dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

It really depend on a few factors where the application is running. Since you are primarily dealing with String, you should be able to get a String of length Integer.MAX_VALUE [always 2147483647 (2^31 - 1] by the Java specification, the maximum size of an array, which the String class uses for internal storage] or half your maximum heap size (since each character is two bytes), whichever is smaller. Ensure that in your application design, the jvm usage on heap does not exceed the allocated or you will get the out of memory error.

Comment: I dont see how this has anything to do with String.

Comment: `setString` parameter is `String`, this parameter eventually will be convert to byte internally before it is sent to the database. `statement` object will use more heap as more `setString` is called. So to answer what is the maximum number of parameter sets that can added to `PreparedStatement` batch update in definite, I am explaining by telling the affecting factors.

Comment: Sorry, correct me if I'm wrong - the Strings that are going to be added as params are already in memory, if their size was going to be an issue wouldn't that happen at the time that they are created/read? 
If yes then isn't the limiting factor for the PreparedStatement going to be the related to the max packet size for the DB or some other network/DB constraint?

Comment: Yes, the String that are going to be added as `params` are already in memory. To be precise, the heap size is used when `params` two dimensional array are declared and assigned with values. When you call method `setString` in the `PreparedStatement`, essentially that is pass by value, equivalent increase the amount of heap usage during the loop.

Comment: Now, you can run a test and check the heap size during the for loop, you will noticed that increment. Before you talk about method `executeBatch`, you better think about if you have run out of memory or still have enough memory at that point. I do not know exactly how the network or its packet size, but at this point if you do not encounter oom, the database driver should handle that packet splitting for you.